open ai assistant plugin problem into filament 3
enter image description here
this was the problem
hey guys please i have a problem ,'cause I'm currently working with filament 3 and i'm using a openai assistant plugin , the problem is after fixing all the setup problem finally this assistant works but it answering me by the same question that i'm asking him
